# How can I specify a unique/different App struct for each target?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an xcode project with different targets, and depending on which target is being built, I want to use a different `@main` App struct. Where can i specify in my target the actual main App struct to be used to load / run the app? Also, how could I do that for the app icon as well.

I tried looking into the settings of each target and i was unable to find any place to specify this.

Comment: Each target having a different `@main` is the default behaviour. Which type of targets are you creating? What problem are you actually running into? Please show a [mcve] of the steps you took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot in settings. Changing an app icon should be one of them.

[image: Selecting app icon per target]

The rest I find it most helpful to do by duplicating/branching files and then select which target should use which files.

For resources you could for instance have one assets per target plus shared assets.

[image: Splitting files per target]

So in your case to split the `@main` you would create two main files, possibly with same name but in different folders. You would select a target for each of the files and have a separate implementation for them.

You can do pretty much any kind of per-target branching with this second approach. There is even no need to change the app icon name as you can reuse the same name but include a different asset catalog.